# Is partition pruning working in Postgres 11 for Update statements

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I've started to use postgresql 11 recently and I encountered with one interesting behavior.

I created table "conversions" with partitions (logdate is a key).

```
CREATE TABLE conversions(
  .....
  logdate timestamp without time zone,
  ....
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
CREATE INDEX ON conversions(logdate);
--
CREATE unique INDEX conversions_log_id_idx ON conversions(logdate, id);
CREATE INDEX conversions_log_is_created_idx ON conversions(logdate, is_created);
```

The partition pruning works for SELECT statements (as describes in documentation):

```
SELECT *
      FROM conversions
WHERE logdate BETWEEN to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');


"Append  (cost=0.42..11134.74 rows=13051 width=1715)"
"  Subplans Removed: 12"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2017q03_logdate_idx on conversions_y2017q03  (cost=0.42..10962.37 rows=13038 width=1715)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_default_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_default  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2030)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
```

It works well, you can see it before.

But it doesn't work for update statements.

As example:

```
UPDATE conversions
  SET is_created = 'N'
WHERE logdate BETWEEN to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

"Update on conversions  (cost=0.42..11069.48 rows=13051 width=1727)"
"  Update on conversions_y2016q04"
"  Update on conversions_y2017q01"
"  Update on conversions_y2017q02"
"  Update on conversions_y2017q03"
"  Update on conversions_y2017q04"
"  Update on conversions_y2018q01"
"  Update on conversions_y2018q02"
"  Update on conversions_y2018q03"
"  Update on conversions_y2018q04"
"  Update on conversions_y2019q01"
"  Update on conversions_y2019q02"
"  Update on conversions_y2019q03"
"  Update on conversions_y2019q04"
"  Update on conversions_default"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2016q04_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2016q04  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=1661)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2017q01_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2017q01  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=1804)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2017q02_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2017q02  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=1805)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2017q03_logdate_idx on conversions_y2017q03  (cost=0.42..10962.37 rows=13038 width=1727)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2017q04_logdate_id_idx on conversions_y2017q04  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=1699)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2018q01_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2018q01  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2018q02_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2018q02  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2018q03_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2018q03  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2018q04_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2018q04  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2019q01_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2019q01  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2019q02_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2019q02  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2019q03_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2019q03  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_y2019q04_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_y2019q04  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
"  ->  Index Scan using conversions_default_logdate_is_created_idx on conversions_default  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2036)"
"        Index Cond: ((logdate >= to_date('2017-09-01 00:00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (logdate <= to_date('2017-09-08 23:59:59'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))"
```

It looks like Postgresql are using index for seeking neccesary partitions.

Is it good behavior? You thoughts?

Comment: have you tried changing between clause to `logdate >= date'' and logdate < date'' `?

Comment: As far as I know this is a limitation of the current implementation. If I understand it correctly there will be major enhancements in that area in Postgres 12

Comment: > have you tried changing between clause to logdate >= date'' and logdate < date'' 
Yes, I tried. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using prepared statements?  If so, a generic plan may be used, which means the planner won't be able to perform pruning because the values needed to do it would only be made available when executing the generic plan.  `SELECT` supports *execution-time pruning* as of PostgreSQL 11, so it's okay even if planner can't do the pruning in its case.  However, for `UPDATE`, only the planner can perform pruning, so there is none if a generic plan is used.  I suspected that you may be using prepared statement, because looking at the `SELECT`'s explain output shared in the question:

```
"Append  (cost=0.42..11134.74 rows=13051 width=1715)"
"  Subplans Removed: 12"
```

it's clear that *run-time pruning* is being used. Read more about partition pruning here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITION-PRUNING

EDIT: I would like to also mention that UPDATE can use pruning if the planner gets a change to do so (non-generic plan), provided you're using `LIST` and `RANGE` partitioning (doesn't work with `HASH` that's new in PostgreSQL 11).

EDIT 2: As mentioned in the comment, this seems to have to do with the fact that OP is using `to_date` function in the where clause which makes the expression being compared to partition key an immutable expression, as far as PostgreSQL is concerned.  That means planner cannot perform pruning with it, although executor can because it's still a stable expression.  As I said above, executor pruning is not supported for UPDATEs.

Comment: I didn't use any prepare statements. You can see it above ) I compare this behavior with such database as Oracle where skipping partitions works well.

Comment: As far as I understood PostgreSQL uses index for searching  partition at first, and finally, it scans only neccecary partitions. It looks logical, but it's different in comparison  with Oracle

Comment: I think I understand why partition pruning doesn't seem to be working for UPDATE.  The answer is still that it's because runtime pruning doesn't work for UPDATE.  Runtime pruning must be used because you're using `to_date` function in the where clause, which is not an immutable function in PostgreSQL.  For plan-time pruning to work, the value being compared to partition key must be an immutable expression.  To fix, you will have to stop using `to_date` function and specify the timestamp value to be compared as literal, so that planner can also prune and UPDATE will also work as expected.

Comment: explain analyze
update conversions c
set  is_created = null  
where c.is_created = 'Y'
 AND c.logdate >= '2018-01-12'::timestamp AND c.logdate < '2018-05-12'::timestamp


is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

using ::timestamp casting, rather than to_timestamp();

example)

where reg_dt >= '2023-08-04 01:00:00'::timestamp
and   reg_dt <= '2023-08-04 02:00:00'::timestamp